# Remove from TensorFlow collection

Tags: tensorflow

I use `tf.add_to_collection("tensor", tensor)` to save operation and `tf.get_from_collection("tensor", tensor)` to restore it later. The problem is that at some point I modify the graph and want to replace one operation with another. If I do another `tf.add_to_collection("tensor", tensor)` then `tf.get_from_collection("tensor", tensor)` has two items. Is there any way to replace or remove operation from a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems like the following works:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.clear_collection("tensor")
```